# Unexpected output at the end of printing an array of char

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned char ch,i,letters[95];
    int tapped [0];
    ch=32; //start with 32 (space)

    while(ch<=127){
        ch++;
        letters[i]=ch;
        i++;
    } 
    printf(letters);


    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get the ASCII characters from 32 to 127 into an array so I can generate N random ones in another loop.

The issue is that I'm getting back all of them, but I'm also getting back some additional unexpected at the end:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\200\300\367\277_\377
```

I don't understand why I'm getting \200\300\367\277_\377 at the end, since they aren't in the range. I'm new to C so is there some aspects of arrays that I'm not doing properly?

Comment: You forgot to add a null terminator to the string.

Comment: When you fix that, don't forget to increase the size to `letters[96]`

Comment: And make sure that `i` does not reach 94. Also `printf("%s", letters)` would be better

Comment: I worked when i changed ch<=127 to ch<127

Comment: I tried using rand() but it says that it doesnt support in C?

Comment: You're also skipping the space character, because you increase `ch` before assigning it to the array. If you want to include it you'll have to increase it after the assignment. This also causes another issue: When you have `while(ch <= 127)` and increment `ch` before assigning it you'll end up assigning when `ch == 128`.

Comment: To use `rand()` include `<stdlib .h>`

Comment: You'll also want to seed rand.

Answer (score 4):

First, if you count the characters from 32 to 127, there are 96 of them. So `letters` should be defined with `letters[96]`, not `letters[95]`.

Second, you should not pass `letters` to `printf` as the first parameter. The first parameter should be a format string, not a string to be printed literally. In particular, since `letters` contains a “%” character, it is not a proper format string.

Third, when printing a string, `printf` expects a null-terminated string by default. To print an array of `char` that is not null-terminated, you can use a precision in the conversions specifier:

```
printf("%.96s\n", letters);
```

Fourth, you say you want all the characters from 32 to 127, but your loop starts with `ch` set to 32 and increments it before putting it into the array, so the first value put into the array is 33. You should nove the increment to later.

Fifth, you do not initialize `i`. It must be set to zero before starting the loop.